# Connecting New Thermostat C Wire To Transformer

Tags: wiring, thermostat

Looking to add a C wire to my 2 zone system (new smart thermostat). Since the original wiring was 2 wire, I ran a new set of 5 wire lines.

The link below shows how my current set-up is wired to the 24V transformer, zone valves, and boiler (Burnham 3WFH):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Cax.jpg

Question:

1. Should I attach the new C wire from the thermostat to the C or R side of the transformer?

Comment: Can you double-check the original wiring for thermostat #1? With the way your diagram shows it, zone 1 would be running constantly...

Comment: You're absolutely correct. The white wire in the "R' connection (black on the diagram due to white background) is actually leaving the thermostat from the "W" connection. Everything else appears to be correct on the diagram.

Comment: Is there a jumper between Rc and R at thermostat #1, then?

Comment: Correct. Apologies on making this difficult to diagnose.